# save "return" to use for later calculations

Tags: c#, get, set, return

I am working on a piece of code that collects data from a website, and save it as arrays. But as I am need to run the same analysis on multiple "stocks/financial instruments" - i want to store the arrays and not overwrite when loading new instrument. Should i use the GET SET functionality?
Code example below:

```
static public double[] OpenColumn(IEnumerable<string> strs, int highNum)//, int highNum2)
    {
        var columnQueryOpen = from line in strs
                              let elements = line.Split(',')
                              select Convert.ToDouble(elements[highNum]);
        var resultsOpen = columnQueryOpen.ToList();
        double[] openPrice = resultsOpen.ToArray();
        return openPrice;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accumulate somewhere your results, for example.

```
static List<double> list = new List<double>();
static public void OpenColumn(IEnumerable<string> strs, int highNum)//, int highNum2)
    {
        var columnQueryOpen = from line in strs
                              let elements = line.Split(',')
                              select Convert.ToDouble(elements[highNum]);
        list.AddRange(columnQueryOpen.ToList());
    }
```

Or you can return double[] as in your example and just accumulate it in the list somewhere else.

**Update** 
If you want to split stock values by days, than you can use a dictionary:

```
static Dictionary<DateTime, List<double>> stocks = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<double>>(); 

private static void AddStocks(DateTime dt, List<double> values) {
            stocks.Add(new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day), values);
        }
```

Comment: wouldn't this add it all to one single string? I need it separated out, so i can compare one stock with another... day-by-day